# Fractional and irrational matrix powers

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

What is a good reference to learn the basics about raising a matrix to a rational power or an irrational power? So I am interested in the existence and computation of things like $A^{\frac{1}{3}}$ or $A^{\pi}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good reference is the recent book:
Nicolas J Higham: "Functions of matrices   Theory and computation"
 SIAM 2008 Society of Industrial and Applied Mathematics